# How to read an integer from a python socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I am using this code segment to read an 32-bit integer from a Python socket:

```
toread=4
buf = bytearray(toread)
view = memoryview(buf)
while toread:
    nbytes = connection.recv_into(view)
    toread-=nbytes
```

Apparently, the integer can be read off from view after this code, but I tried to print out `view` directly and cannot retrieve the integer that has been read. Any idea?

Comment: *the integer can be read off from view after this code...* No, you have to explicitly convert bytes to in with `int.from_bytes()`

Comment: The view here isn't really necessary.  `bfr = connection.recv(4)` and `val = int.from_bytes(bfr,'little')` or `val=struct.unpack('I',bfr)[0]` will do the job just fine.

Comment: Looks like answers above. Thanks!

Comment: Although, checking the return value of `.recv(4)` is recommended.  `.recv(4)` will read 1-4 bytes or 0 on connection close.  Make sure you receive all the data you requested.